# Does this question have a logical fallacy? [Find the poloynomial satisfying the below condtions.]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This might be silly question, I would ask for your understanding. I got this question from my friend.

$Q)$ Find $f(-1)$ satifying the below condtions from $(1)$ to $(3)$

$(1)$ Dividing the polynomial $f$ by $g$, its quotient and remainder are both
$g(x)-3x^2$.

$(2)$ Leading coefficient of the $f$ is $6$

$(3)$ $f(1) = -4$.

$(sol)$ By the Polynomial Remainder Theorem

$f(x) = g(x)(g(x) -3x^2) + (g(x)-3x^2)$ with $min\{ deg g(x), deg(g(x) - 3x^2)\} > deg(g(x)-3x^2)$

Since the $f$ is polynomail, $g$ is polynomial.

Therefore $deg(g(x)-3x^2) =0$ which means $g(x) = 3x^2 + a, a \in \mathbb{R}$

Substituting $g(x)$, We can get $f(x) = 3ax^2 + (a^2 + a)$.

From the $f(1) = -4, a = -2$.

My answer is There aren't $f$ because of the $f(x) = -6x^2 +6 $ which is contradiction with the condition $(2)$.

So conlcusion is this question has a logical fallacy. Is my conclusion right?

Comment: Can the remainder $g(x) - 3x^2$ have degree $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degree of the remainder $g(x)-3x^2$ is less than the degree of the divisor $g$. If (the contrary) that:

- $g$ has degree more than $2$, then $g(x) -3x^2$ has the same degree as $g$; or
- $g$ has degree less than $2$, then $g(x) - 3x^2$ has degree $2$, which is more than the degree of $g$.

So $g$ has degree $2$, and the degree of $g(x)-3x^2$ would be at most $1$. Your missing case was from concluding $g(x)-3x^2$ is a constant.

Let $g(x) - 3x^2 = bx+a$ where $a,b\in \mathbb R$, i.e. $g(x) = 3x^2 +bx+a$. The division gives

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= g(x) \left[g(x)-3x^2\right] + \left[g(x)-3x^2\right]\\
&= \left[g(x)+1\right] \left[g(x)-3x^2\right]\\
&= \left(3x^2 + bx + a + 1\right)\left(bx+a\right)
\end{align*}$$

From condition $(2)$, the leading coefficient $3b=6$, i.e. $b=2$.

From condition $(3)$,

$$\begin{align*}
f(1) &= -4\\
\left(3\cdot 1^2 + 2\cdot1 + a + 1\right)\left(2\cdot1+a\right) &= -4\\
\left(a+6\right)\left(a+2\right) &= -4\\
a &= -4
\end{align*}$$

The $f$ and $f(-1)$ are therefore

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \left(3x^2 + 2x -4 + 1\right)\left(2x-4\right)\\
f(-1) &= \left[3(-1)^2 +2 (-1) -4+1\right]\left[2(-1)-4\right]\\
&= 12
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

To begin with,

$$\min\{ \deg g(x), \deg(g(x) - 3x^2)\} \leq \deg(g(x) - 3x^2) $$
by the definition of $\min$, so

$$\min\{ \deg g(x), \deg(g(x) - 3x^2)\} \stackrel?> \deg(g(x)-3x^2)$$
cannot be true.

The mistake here is in looking at the degrees of both polynomials in the product
$g(x)(g(x) -3x^2)$. The degree of the quotient is irrelevant.
Only the degree of the divisor matters:
$$\deg g(x) > \deg(g(x)-3x^2).$$

It is still not possible to conclude from this that $\deg(g(x)-3x^2) = 0$.
However, from the fact that $\deg g(x) \neq \deg(g(x)-3x^2)$
we can deduce $\deg g(x)$ and put an upper bound on $\deg(g(x)-3x^2)$.

You are correct that the "solution" $f(x) \stackrel?= -6x^2 +6$
violates condition $(2)$, since the leading coefficient would then be $-6$ rather than $6$.

A correct solution should actually **use** condition $(2)$.
It gives useful information about what the coefficients of $g(x)$ can be.